# Rails - Associating a model with a user

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, associations

I've just started a Rails application set up with Devise. Now, I'm planning to add a new model, Product, that will have a one-to-many relationship with User. I've generated the Product model using the scaffold generator. Then, I've added the `belongs_to :user` to product, and `has_many :products` to user. Should I run a migration after adding the associations? I'm using mysql for my database.

Now, I'm unsure of how to associate it with the current user. I'm trying to set the user of the product in the products controller create action. Something like `@product.user = current_user`. But it doesn't actually work. I've read that I should set the user.id of a product to achieve this, but I'm not really sure how to do that. Step-by-step tutorial links and detailed explanations would really help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First run migration of product then make another migration or just add

```
   t.integer :user_id
```

in product migration run migration then you can

```
     @product.user = current_user
```

Comment: So it's really needed to set the id of the product? I thought there was a better way to do it by adding the associations.